# For the Django template {%url%} tag, how do I find all URL arguments from generic view contexts, not just the last?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

In Django, I am trying to make an app with a tree hierarchy of models i.e *Books* containing *Chapters* containing *Sections* etc. I want my URLs to mirror the structure, like *books/3/chapters/5/sections*.

I want to use the generic class-based views. In my HTML templates, I will use the *{% url %}* command to specify link targets.

For URLs deep in the structure, I need to provide *{% url %}* with all the keys that appear in the URL. For the above example: *{% url 'pattern-name' 3 5 %}*

However, the generic class-based views only provide (if that) the primary key of the object they are concerned with in the template context (i.e. in the above: 5).

How do I retrieve the foreign keys of parent objects (i.e. in the above: 3)?

I have the following:

My Models in 
**models.py:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField("Book Name", max_length = 80)

class Chapter(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField("Book Name", max_length = 80)
  book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

My URL patterns in **urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('books/', 
       views.BookListView.as_view(), name='book_list'),
  path('books/<int:book>/', 
       views.BookDetailView.as_view(), name='book_detail'),
  path('books/<int:book>/chapters/', 
       views.ChapterListView.as_view(), name='chapter_list'),
  path('books/<int:book>/chapters/<int:chapter>/',
       views.ChapterDetailView.as_view(), name='chapter_detail'),
  path('books/<int:book>/chapters/create/',
       views.ChapterCreateView.as_view(), name='chapter_create'),
```

My Views in **views.py:**

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
  model = 'Book'

class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
  model = 'Book'
  pk_url_kwarg = 'book'

class ChapterListView(generic.ListView):
  model = 'Chapter'
  def get_queryset(self):
    return Chapter.objects.filter(book = self.kwargs['book'])

class ChapterDetailView(generic.DetailView):
  model = 'Chapter'
  pk_url_kwarg = 'chapter'

class ChapterCreateView(generic.CreateView):
  model = 'Chapter'
  fields = ['name', 'book']
  def get_initial(self):
    initial = super().get_initial().copy()
    initial['book'] = self.kwargs.['book']
    return initial;
```

In my HTML-Template used for the list of chapters, I want to have a link to create a new chapter. Currently, that template looks as follows:

Template **chapter_list.html:**

```
<ul>
{% for chapter in chapter_list %}
  <li>{{ chapter.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'chapter_create' 42 %}">Add new chapter</a>
```

Obviously, I don't want to add all new chapters to the book with ID *42*, rather I would like to use the book ID from the chapter list, where I am at. For example, for an URL

```
.../books/17/chapters/create/
```

I would like to have the link point to:

```
<a href="{% url 'chapter_create' 17 %}">Add new chapter</a>
```

The only way I have found of doing this dynamically, is to add extra context to the chapter list view:

Updated **views.py:**

```
...

class ChapterListView(generic.ListView):
  model = 'Chapter'
  def get_queryset(self):
    return Chapter.objects.filter(book = self.kwargs['book'])

  # Additional Context
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['my_current_book_id'] = self.kwargs['book']
    return context

...
```

And then have the template say:

Updated **chapter_list.html:**

```
<ul>
{% for chapter in chapter_list %}
  <li>{{ chapter.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'chapter_create' my_current_book_id %}">Add new chapter</a>
```

Here is my question:

Is there no easier (i.e more Django-ish built-in) way to do this?

It seems to me, that this must be a very commonplace task, and that with the beautiful and fine-grained design of the generic view classes and URL (reverse-)lookups, I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider defining `get_absolute_url` for the `book_detail` and `chapter_detail`, and extra methods for other URLs like `chapter_create`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Book Name", max_length = 80)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book_detail', args=[self.pk])

    def get_create_chapter_url(self):
        return reverse('chapter_create', args=[self.pk])


class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Book Name", max_length = 80)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('chapter_detail', args=[self.book_pk, self.pk])
```

Then in the template, you can use `{{ chapter.get_absolute_url }}`, `{{ book.get_absolute_url }}`, `{{ chapter.book.get_create_chapter_url }}` and so on, and you don't need to worry about what parameters are in the URLs.

In the chapter detail view, you can use the foreign key to access methods on the `Book` model:

```
{{ chapter.book.get_absolute_url }}
```

In the chapter list view, you need to add the book to the context (in case there are no chapters in the book):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ChapterListView(generic.ListView):
    model = 'Chapter'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Chapter.objects.filter(book = self.kwargs['book'])

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['book'] = get_object_or_404(pk=self.kwargs['book'])
      return context
```

Then you can access the `{{ book }}` in the context.

Or you can use a `DetailView` for the chapter list view, using the `Book` model:

```
class ChapterListView(generic.DetailView):
    model = 'Book'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'book'
```

Then `book` is already in the template context, and you can loop through the related chapters with:

```
{% for chapter in book.chapter_set.all %}
  {{ chapter }}
{% endfor %}
```

As an aside, it might be simpler to leave out the `book` field in the create view. Then set it in the `form_valid` method before saving the form.

```
class ChapterCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = 'Chapter'
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=self.kwargs['book'])
        form.instance.book = book
        return super(ChapterCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Very interesting! I have by now implemented `get_absolute_url()` for Chapter and Book, mainly to provide `success_url`s for the matching `CreateView` and `EditView` specializations. I like the idea of providing a `get_create_chapter_url()` to the book model. However, how would I access it from the `chapter_list.html` template context, where all I have is a (possbily empty) list of chapters `chapter_list`?

Comment: You just need to make sure that `book` is in the template context. I've added some more examples.

Comment: I've used this solution now and it works fine! Also, the aside about `form_valid()` was valuable to me (I edited it to correct some minor syntax errors). I was unsure before, how I could leave the book id out of the form displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a view with the `Book` as model and:

```
{% for chapter in book.chapter_set.all %}
```

Comment: With regards to the first solution: If I am in `chapter_list.html`, I only have a list object `chapter_list` available, which may be empty. So there may be no chapter to look into.

Comment: With regards to the second solution, if I have a deep hierarchy `A/B/C/D`, wouldn't this lead to a situation, where I only have views with `A` as model and DB accesses like `A.B_set.C_set.D_set.all` in the templates?

Comment: Ah, I see, I hadn't thought of that problem in the first solution, and I was thinking about it the wrong way, actually, I don't think it would be a nice solution. Regarding the second option, my suggestion was for this particular view, it doesn't mean all your views have to be like that (and it wouldn't be nested, that wouldn't work). That said, I don't have any problem with your solution. Either way you have to get the book id to the template. Having the `Book` as model emphasizes that this is a view of a book, not just a list of chapters.